# Problem pass props to component using called function and spread operators with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that should return an object with children to populate a component using spread operators but it's not working.

I'm on React using Chakra as UI framework and constants to escale properties.

My component is a button which I'm applying styles and then calling a function that should return more styles.

```js
import {textCrop} from '../utils/textCrop.js'

function cta(props) {
  const {colors, title} = props
  const buttonColors = [
    {
      bg: "black",
      color: "white",
      border: "none",
      iconColor: "red",
    },
    (...)
  ]
  const buttonStyle = {
    ...textCrop, /* spread operator to call all function properties */
    bgColor: buttonColors[color].bg,
    (...)
  }
  return (
    <chakra.button {...buttonStyle}>{title}</chakra.button>
  )
}
```

The called function `textCrop()` code is this:

```
const textCrop = (lineHeightSize = 1.3, topAdjustment = 0, bottomAdjustment = 0) => {
  const topCrop = 5;
  const bottomCrop = 5;
  const cropFontSize = 16;
  const cropLineHeight = 1.3125;

  const dynamicTopCrop = (topCrop + (lineHeightSize - cropLineHeight) * (cropFontSize / 2)) / cropFontSize;

  const dynamicBottomCrop = (bottomCrop + (lineHeightSize - cropLineHeight) * (cropFontSize / 2)) / cropFontSize;

  const marginBottom = `-${dynamicTopCrop + topAdjustment}em`;

  const marginTop = `-${dynamicBottomCrop + bottomAdjustment}em`;

  return {
    lineHeight: lineHeightSize,
    _before: {
      content: '""',
      display: 'block',
      height: 0,
      width: 0,
      marginBottom: marginBottom,
    },
    _after: {
      content: '""',
      display: 'block',
      height: 0,
      width: 0,
      marginTop: marginTop,
    }
  }
}

export {
  textCrop
}
```

It's based on [EightShapes Text Crop](https://text-crop.eightshapes.com/) adaptation made [here](https://github.com/eanesparrago/study-text-crop) for styled-components.

Console is returning this for the function:

```
text crop function textCrop() {
  var lineHeightSize = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : 1.3;
  var topAdjustment = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : 0;
  var bottomAdjustment = arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] !== undefined ? arguments[2] : 0;
  var topCrop = 5;
  var bottomCrop = 5;
  var cropFontSize = 16;
  var cropLineHeight = 1.3125;
  var dynamicTopCrop = (topCrop + (lineHeightSize - cropLineHeight) * (cropFontSize / 2)) / cropFontSize;
  var dynamicBottomCrop = (bottomCrop + (lineHeightSize - cropLineHeight) * (cropFontSize / 2)) / cropFontSize;
  var marginBottom = "-".concat(dynamicTopCrop + topAdjustment, "em");
  var marginTop = "-".concat(dynamicBottomCrop + bottomAdjustment, "em");
  return {
    lineHeight: lineHeightSize,
    _before: {
      content: '""',
      display: 'block',
      height: 0,
      width: 0,
      marginBottom: marginBottom
    },
    _after: {
      content: '""',
      display: 'block',
      height: 0,
      width: 0,
      marginTop: marginTop
    }
  };
}
```

I believe it should be returning only the object from `textCrop()`. If I try reaching for children like `textCrop.lineHeight` it gives me the value of undefined.
No pseudo-elements are being rendered within `<button>`.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: it should be ...textCrop() right  ? not ...textCrop

Comment: Yes. That was it. I didn't know it would be passed as a function(). Thanks! Want to anwser it so I can mark it as the correct one or can I anwser it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call it as a function  `{...textCrop()}` inorder to get the returned value from the function